# Preview is Not Remembering Window Sizes and Positions on Startup (after Update to High Sierra)

Tags: high-sierra, pdf, preview

Since I updated to High Sierra the Preview app no longer remembers the sizes and positions of its open windows. Instead it just opens all windows on the same desktop with standardised size and position when the computer starts up.

How do I fix this?

(Side note: After updating the Preview app also didn't remember the last viewed page of PDF-files, but I was able to fix this by deleting the `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview` folder. However, the window size and position issue persists.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preview does remember the position of windows containing images (JPG, PNG, etc) but for some reason does not restore the position of PDF windows. I suspect this is a bug.

The saved state for Preview is located at: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`

Meanwhile, you can use an app like [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/) to remember and automatically reset the position of any window. It’s a bit heavy handed for this use case but it would let you carry on until the bug is fixed.

You might also look at window managers such as [Tiles](https://freemacsoft.net/tiles/) or [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com) that allow easy manipulation of windows.

Comment: Are you sure this is a general bug? I can't find anyone else reporting the same problem.

Comment: Well it happens for me (image windows remembered, PDF windows not remembered)

Comment: I had noticed this issue, but it didn’t bother me. I appreciate you must have a workflow where it is bothersome.

Comment: Do you see image windows maintaining their position?

Comment: Yes, image windows do seem to maintain their position. I just checked with a .png file.

Comment: I have sent feedback to Apple about this bug. I hope they will fix it in a future update.

Comment: I’ve also reported it.

Comment: Still broken in 10.13.4 

Comment: Still broken in 10.15.5 

Comment: Still broken in 11.3.1 

Comment: this is infuriating!!!!

Comment: Still broken in 12.6